# selenium - wait when editbox is interactable (after button click)

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, xpath, webdriverwait

So I'm trying to learn about interacting with elements, after they are loaded (or enabled/interactable). In this case pressing button enables Edit box (after like 3-4secs), so you can write something. Here's link:
http://the-internet.herokuapp.com/dynamic_controls

Here is how it looks now - works, but what if this edit-box would load, for example, 6 seconds? Then it'd be wrecked up...

```
enable = browser.find_element(By.XPATH, "/html/body/div[2]/div/div[1]/form[2]/button")
enable.click()
time.sleep(5)
fillform = browser.find_element(By.XPATH, "/html/body/div[2]/div/div[1]/form[2]/input")           
fillform.send_keys("testtt")
time.sleep(1)
```

I also tried  browser.implicitly_wait(20)  but it is like ignored and does nothing. Browser just keeps closing, because it can't find ENABLED edit box. It gives the error:

selenium.common.exceptions.ElementNotInteractableException: Message: element not interactable

I've tried another method for this - didn't work, as well...

> element = WebDriverWait(browser, 5).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "/html/body/div[2]/div/div[1]/form[2]/input")))

I am using Chrome+Python.

Comment: after clicking the "Enable" button wait for input box to be intractable using WebDriver Wait

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `WebDriverWait()` and wait for `element_to_be_clickable()`. Also use  the following `xpath` option.

```
driver.get('http://the-internet.herokuapp.com/dynamic_controls')
WebDriverWait(driver,10).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//button[text()='Enable']"))).click()
WebDriverWait(driver,10).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//form[@id='input-example']//input"))).send_keys("testtt")
```

browser snapshot:

[image]

Comment: Okay, it finally did the work! You used different elements than I used, I see